# Directed graph layout engines on .NET / Silverlight / JavaScript / Flash

Tags: c#, javascript, flash, silverlight, graph

Who knows good graph layout engines with clear customization and managment?

[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/launch/apps/dependency_graph) is an cool one but it is written on Flex (may be you know how it can be customized without re-compilation and writing code?). I also know about [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) but it not good enough.

Comment: what do you mean by "graph", do you main Pie Charts etc, or do you mean "nodes" that connect to each other with "links"?

Comment: I mean graphs as a set of nodes and verticles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/ on Silverlight. Not sure if it works on Silverlight or just regular WPF though.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  Graph# looks brilliant and despite there being no documentation on CodePlex, there is a tutorial at http://sachabarber.net/?p=815.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how good it is, but Microsoft has [MSAGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Automatic_Graph_Layout).

Comment: Thanks, but as I know it is paid and not web enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using Flash you could have a look at [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/).